# window only appears after click on screen

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, xfce

I am using pygtk for a gui on a touchscreen computer for a machine user-interface. The user can save at any moment the actual configuration of the machine. When he presses on a button "save config", a virtual keyboard, which I implemented, appears on screen to enable him to introduce the configuration name. My problem is that this keyboard doesn't appear directly after pressing on button "save config". One should wait for a next click anywhere on screen to make it appear.

Here is class `keyboard`:

```
class keyboard():

def __init__(self):     

    window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL) 
    window.set_position(1)
    window.set_keep_above(True)
    window.connect("destroy", lambda w: window.destroy())
    window.set_transient_for(self.gui.window) #self.gui.window is the main window
    window.set_destroy_with_parent(True)
    window.set_skip_taskbar_hint(True)
    window.set_skip_pager_hint(True)
    window.connect("delete_event",window.hide_on_delete)
    window.deiconify()
    window.set_type_hint(gtk.gdk.WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_SPLASHSCREEN)
    window.set_size_request(KBD_WIN_WIDTH,KBD_WIN_HEIGHT)
    window.set_resizable(False)

    table = gtk.Table(rows=5, columns=12, homogeneous=True)
    frame = gtk.Frame()
    frame.add(table)
    window.add(frame)
    """
    ... code to fill the table with buttons
    """
    self.window = window
```

And here is the call back function called after clicking on button 'save config':

```
def save_cfg_clicked(self,widget):
    keyboard_ = keyboard(self)
    keyboard_.window.set_keep_above(True)
    keyboard_.window.set_modal(True)
    keyboard_.window.show_all()
```

I've tried several things like calling the function `window.show_all` with `gobject.idle_add`, but that didn't help.

Please note that I am using an xfce desktop. This problem doesn't appear when the program runs on Gnome.

Comment: Sounds like a window manager problem. Some window managers want you to click on the screen in order to decide where to place the window. I'm not aware of Xfce doing this, but TWM definitely does this. Maybe attaching a mouse will illustrate this more clearly instead of using a touchscreen?

Comment: The problem remains when I click on the button with a mouse

Comment: What I mean to say is, when the window is first created, the window manager generally creates an outline (that moves with your mouse cursor). Once clicked, the window is placed where the outline is, and appears. Only reason why I suggested a mouse is to make it more obvious if the outline is there (to confirm whether my theory is correct).

Comment: Because of the line `window.set_position(1)`, the window always appears in the center and is not related to the position of the cursor at the last click. However, I found a round-about, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When removing the line :

```
window.set_transient_for(self.gui.window)
```

the problem dissapears.